# Data Disable With not enable button after a send a file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ujs

I am building a rails app that only deals with request json and will return the information to the user. I am trying to use the data-disable-with property, but after the action finish the button is not being enable. 
I am requesting a Endpoint and the JSON response I will generate a XLSX file and send to the user. 
The problem is that after the file has been send the button is not enable.

```
<%= form_for generate_report_path, url: generate_report_path(format: "xlsx"), method: :post do %>
 <div class="form-group">
 <%= label_tag(:dtInicio, "Data Inicio") %>
 <%= text_field_tag(:dtInicio, nil, class: "form-control datepicker", id: 'cpDtInicio', placeholder: "Pesquise a data inicio",  required: true) %>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
 <%= label_tag(:dtFinal, "Data Final") %>
 <%= text_field_tag(:dtFinal, nil, class: "form-control datepicker", id: 'cpDtFinal', placeholder: "Pesquise a data Final", required: true) %>
 </div>
 <%= button_tag("Download", class: "btn btn-dark", id: 'download', 'data-disable-with' => "<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Gerando Relatório...")  %>
 <div class="col-md-12"></div>
<% end %>
```

On my controller:

```
def generate_report
    begin_dt = Date.parse(params[:dtInicio]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    end_dt = Date.parse(params[:dtFinal]).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    @info = JSON.parse(get_connection(begin_dt, end_dt))["information"]

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx {        
        send_file generate_file, content_type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 
          filename: "#{Time.now.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S%L')}.xlsx", :disposition => 'inline'
        }
    end
end
```

I already try to add a JS to enable, but the page is not reloading for this JS be executed. I'm lost and appreciate the help.

Comment: have you thought about using the data attribute: `disable_with`? Check the documentation for this Rails feature regarding the disabling of submits: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag

Comment: Hey @JohnBaker, thanks for trying to help. Yeah, that is what I'm using, but after the submit the button, is no longer enable. The file is returned but the button continue disable.

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer for this question. But it seems nobody knows or there is no way of doing that.

Comment: @Repolês I also can't make work like it should. The app was rewritten in JavaScript a year ago.
If is an option for you and you don't need to process anything, make the request in Ajax e return the file for the user it will work better.

Comment: Thanks, @Francisco. I gonna try that!